# Running E2E tests with Detox and Android emulator on mac m1

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, apple-m1, detox

I have some troubleshoot when running detox e2e tests on Android emulator with my Macbook pro m1 (Apple chipset)

I want to know if it's only me or if there is others with the same difficulty ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with M1, I solved it by upgrading detox to `19.9.2`

Answer (score -2):

I do. Randomly having issue like this

```
The pending request #-1000 ("isReady") has been rejected
```